# how to avoid "undefined" appearing in a string when a string is not defined- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 variables which are dynamic and might be `null` or `undefined`.

Example:

```
var str1= " hello";
var str2= " world";
var str= " how are you?";
```

and now I'm concatenating these string together to form a query in my searchlist:

```
query = str1&& str1 + str2&& str2 + str3&& str3; //o/p: "hello world how are you?
```

this results fine, however in any case when one of the str value is null or empty, I get this whe I concatenate these string:

```
query = str1&& str1 + str2&& str2 + str3&& str3; // o/p: "hello world undefined"
```

How can I avoid this undefined coming in my string?

Comment: What do want show instead? Initialize your String with that! You can also check `str.className == “undefined’ `before concatnation

Comment: Maybe I have OCD but it bugs me that your converting strings to boolean results then adding the boolean results and Im surprised your getting a string result at all. I am further bugged that your &&ing the same variable and code like theres any expectation of a value other than true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the logical or operator to provide a default value in case any string is null or undefined.

```
query = (str1 || '') + (str2 || '') + (str3 || '')
```

You can use the nullish coalescing operator to only provide default values for null and undefined and not for other falsey values. Remember to check the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing).

```
query = (str1 ?? '') + (str2 ?? '') + (str3 ?? '')
```

Comment: I would avoid the coalesce as support for it is poor at the moment